# Swift debugger not showing list of doubles for Xcode7

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am trying to debug a Swift program in Xcode7 however the debugger does not show list of Doubles correctly.

The values are still correct just incorrectly shown.
The build configuration is set to debug, and I have no code optimization on.
The debugger does show list of Ints and Strings correctly.

This is for all list of Doubles in the program. 
On the same computer I can debug a different Swift program just fine.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH1C7.jpg) of the debugger for the broken debugger.

Answer (score 0):

For science, I tried this on Xcode 7.1.1(7B1005) on a Playground and it obviously worked fine:

[image: playground]

What happens if you move the code outside of viewDidLoad?

Comment: The same problem exists everywhere in the program.